# How to receive and pass on an HTTP request in PHP

Tags: php, xml, api, http, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use an API that does not have any documentation.  I have an 3rd party application that sends XML messages to an API when you give it a username, password and URL of the API.  I need to intercept that message, modify it and send it on.  ( I'm not hacking, I'm trying to get 2 systems to work together in a non-default way ).

I can get system A to send the message to my own webserver, and read the message.

I see the username and password passed in the $_system variables.

> Key: PHP_AUTH_USER; Value: MY-USERNAME
>    Key: PHP_AUTH_PW;
>   Value: MY-PASSWORD
>    Key: REQUEST_TIME; Value: 1327097007

I can see the XML message in the BODY too

> ```
> > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE enterprise SYSTEM
> > "ldisp-2.0.dtd"><enterprise><properties>... [snip]
> ```

How do I take this message that I just recieved and send it exactly as is to another system ?  All I know about the API is :

1. The URL : https://3rd-party-company.com/api/
2. My password with the 3rd party-company : MY-PASSWORD
3. My username with the 3rd party-company : MY-USERNAME
4. The XML which was in the body of the HTTP request.

How can I resend it to the URL it it supposed to go to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to do that.
Basically you receive the response in your script and then create a new one and send it to the other host using cURL.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special to enable your php script receive a HTTP request as long as your php script is running in a web server like Apache.

To make an outgoing HTTP call you can use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) or even [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for finer control over HTTP request.